# Checking exact match in collection with Spring JPA

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a query that checks if a collection does not contain certain elements then return the result but I was wondering if there is a better way to write this either using native SQL or JPQL

```
  @Query("from User u where ?1 not member of u.roles and ?2 not member of u.roles and ?3 not member of u.roles")
  List<User> findAllByRolesIn(Role role1, Role role2, Role role3);
```

I attempted with a Set and passed it as a parameter to check by doing this

```
@Query("from User u where ?1 member of u.roles")
List<User> findAllByRolesIn(Set<Role> roles); // where the three roles are in the set
```

I also attempted using `in` and `not in` but could not get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

See here section 10.2.3.6
https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_collection_dec

I think you need to use something like this:

```
select distinct u from User u join u.roles r where r in ?1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions however this doesn't return the desired result.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does it return?

Comment: What does `Role` look like in your code?  Is it a class or an enum?

Comment: It returns a list users with Role4 and Role1 but I want it to return just users with Role4. If the user has both Role4 and Role1, they shouldn't be selected.  And the Role is a Pojo with one field `String name`